# is there another package similair to torchview for GNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I would like to use torchview for my GNN model. torchview link https://github.com/mert-kurttutan/torchview but it mentions that it is not available for GNN yet. is there a similar package that I can use that can help provide the same visualization.

```
my_model_graph = draw_graph(
    model, input_size=my_dataset.num_node_features)
my_model_graph.visual_graph
```

Error is

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```